# How I get int values from Excel through Openpyxl

Tags: python, numbers, openpyxl

I'm a begining at Python and Openpyxl.

My goal is learning about validating datas from excel, I was going well until I came across with this silly issue which I could get the corrected values of each row (name, state, married, blah blah) but age.

It only returns a str value **"=RANDBETWEEN(11,48)"** instead of numbers.

This is the following code:

```
import openpyxl as excel

fileData = excel.load_workbook("excel_files/dataPeople.xlsx")
fileData_sheet = fileData["Hoja1"]


maxRow = fileData_sheet.max_row
maxCol = fileData_sheet.max_column

kids = {}
adults = {}

for row in range(2, maxRow):
  
    name_cell = "A" + str(row)
    age_cell = "B" + str(row)
    married_cell = "D" + str(row)

    name = fileData_sheet[name_cell].value
    age = fileData_sheet[age_cell].value
    married = fileData_sheet[married_cell].value

    if name or age or married is not None:
        
        print(f"name: {name}, age {age}, married: {married}")

    else:
         break
```

Output

```
name: Braiden, age =RANDBETWEEN(11,48), married: Yes
name: Iliana, age =RANDBETWEEN(11,48), married: No  
name: Justin, age =RANDBETWEEN(11,48), married: No  
name: Kira, age =RANDBETWEEN(11,48), married: No    
name: Camila, age =RANDBETWEEN(11,48), married: Yes 
etc etc
```

Besides this, I'd also like to receive feedbacks about how my code is going so far, I really want to learn and import with good coders.

Comment: got this from a google search, seems like what your looking for.  `wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename, data_only=True)` I never mind answering questions that already have answer on here cause beginners ussually want more information than just an answer and want to ask questions, just keep in mind allot of others dont share my sentiment and get really salty

Answer (score -1):

You could have sent a part of your excel sheet for reference.

But I think I know where the problem is

1- In this line

```
age_cell = "B" + str(row)
```

you are getting the data as a string

```
age_cell = "B" + int(row)
```

this might help.

2- You can also try changing this line

```
age = fileData_sheet[age_cell].value
```

to this

```
age = fileData_sheet[age_cell].value
age = int(age)
```

I hope I understood what you meant correctly.

Comment: his issue is more that openpyxl is returning the formula from his workbook rather than the liter values, which is solved by adding `data_only=True` to the `load_workbook` function

Comment: Indeed, the issua could be solved by adding data_only. Thanks so much Christian and also Diamond (I also thought I missed int() but I got an error as result)